# What can Jsplumb be used for ?

Tags: jquery, jsplumb

I read few articles on jsplumb , but cannot yet understand the usage. I mean what is the use of connecting two elements ? What else can we get from that connection ?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like it's just a cool way to diagram flowcharts.

Comment: It's really just something to help create an intuitive ui. For example, if you were building an application where you connected x number of components together in a flow from an input location to an output location, this plugin would take care of the connecting and dragging part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen this before. But it looks useful for creating workflows. Such as if you were building an app that automated tasks.